# "detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) flutter patch request

Tags: android, ios, flutter, httprequest

I'm trying to do a patch request in flutter using [Requests](https://pub.dev/packages/requests) package, here is my code :

```dart
    var putResponse = await Requests.patch(
      '$shiftUrl',
      headers: {
        'Authorization':
            'Basic eklAV2QmbjAjWSFKT0FIM2pHS0ZPbEt3NyEqcDpvQkcyREVyWWprI1BteA==',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: {
        "difference": 123214,
      },
    );
    print('sssss ${putResponse.content()}');
```

And it always prints this error

```
"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

any help about this ?

Comment: encode your body to json `body: json.encode({body here})` where you need to import `import 'dart:convert';`

Comment: That works for http package... not sure why you're using this package though but it should work